# hot questions change every time page is refreshed

Tags: bug, hot-questions

just noticed this, the hot questions on main page do not seem to be stable at all. clicked "refresh" on a main or meta page and they instantly/constantly change. understand that it would constantly change over time but dont expect it to change one page refresh to the next, that seems like a bug.

Comment: Its not a bug, but it is annoying. Especially that they change with the back button; so many times I've seen something intersting just as I leave the page

Comment: know that its a new algorithm & there has been tinkering but dont think its working right if its totally unstable & seemingly verging on random...

Comment: I have seen same question appearing on the next page, if I change the page after some time, (not all the questions but just couple of them), I agree with @RichardTingle, it is annoying.

Comment: @vzn You've fallen into the "I don't like it so its a bug" trap. Its working exactly as the makers intended so its not a bug. You could however make a *feature request* for it to stop doing this

Comment: can you explain why the makers "intended" for it to be so unstable? it seems more like a randomizer to me.... maybe name should be changed to "random questions list"....

Comment: They are random hot questions, but all are hot for some definition of hot.

Comment: ok. unfortunately this tends to work against "viral" type questions that tend to gain a lot of hits because they are _(stable)_ on the hot question list (tend to like those myself). although have seen complaints about that too (amazingly some sites dislike having hot questions & the corresponding influx of newbies!)

Comment: @vzn you can always get the stable super list by following the 'Hot Network Questions' link which leads to http://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot with 100 such questions.

Comment: ok it would be nice to have an interface to find stable hot questions on a user-selectable subset/filter of sites, or maybe just the top _n_ for _n_ <100. `feature-request`

Comment: On a per-site basis, you can always go to the 'hot' tab: http://stackoverflow.com/?tab=hot